# C# MVC4 Partial View with other ActionResult in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor, model-view-controller, partial-views

i have a problem. 
I have my Controller "DashboardNB2Controller", my View "index.cshtml" and i want to integrate a partial view called "_PartialView.cshtml" in my "index.cshtml". Both Views are in the same folder. In my controller, i have the "ActionResult _PartialView" for a databaseoperation in my partial view.

But if I integrate my partial view in my index view, the action result "_PartialView" didn't work. I get no results. The query for my database is correct. I checked this.

Here are my codes

1. My Controller with the ActionResult for the Partial View

   ```
   public ActionResult _PartialView()
   {
       var lastMessages= (from t in db.view_tbl_message
                                        orderby t.Date descending
                                        select t).Take(10);



       ViewModelDashboard model = new ViewModelDashboard();
       model.view_tbl_message = lastMessages.ToList();


       return PartialView("_PartialView", model);

   }
   ```

My index.cshtml

```
 @model AisWebController.Areas.Statistics.Models.ViewModelDashboard


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

 }

<br />
     @{Html.Action("_PartialView", "DashboardNB2");}

<br />
```

And my _PartialView.cshtml

```
 @model WebApplication.Areas.Stats.Models.ViewModelDashboard

 <table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            User
        </th>
        <th>
            Message
        </th>

    </tr>
 @foreach (var item in Model.view_tbl_message)
 {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message) 
            </td>

        </tr>


    }
</table>
```

If someone can help - that would be aweseome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
 @{Html.Action("_PartialView", "DashboardNB2");}
```

to

```
 @Html.Action("_PartialView", "DashboardNB2")
```

Comment: yw :) . Use {} for RenderAction() as it writes directly to Response stream

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `{}` brackets after you have `@` in view for Html extension methods

Look your `@Html.DisplayFor` it doesn't have any {} brackets.

Same applies for `@Html.ActionLink`